# Unable to get value of the property 'split' after ajax call in IE8

Tags: javascript

I have a array which contains value `02/21/2012 8:00am` and i get this value from custom created sub-json.

So i'm splitting it using

```
var date = jsonData.list[i].mydate.split(" ")[0];
console.log(date);  //shows 02/21/2012
```

Even though it splits and shows the value ,  it throws an error "Unable to get value of the property 'split': object is null or undefined" in IE8 but works fine in IE9, FF.

I also tried

```
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8" />
```

Nothing seem to work.

Comment: Your error says that `jsonData.list[i].mydate` isn't defined. Can you make sure that the `jsonData.list[i].mydate` object exists?

Comment: You can't split null. Debug further e.g. `console.log(jsonData.list[i]);` and `console.log(jsonData.list[i].mydate);` to narrow it down.

Comment: @user1184100: On IE as well? Your error says that it doesn't exist.

Comment: `split()` doesn't work in IE8 as i know.

Comment: thanks all for the reply, based on the suggestions i tried jsonData.list[i].mydate and one of the values in json data  was showing "undefined" and this happens only in IE8 so i added the condition if(jsonData.list[i].mydate!=undefined){} ... it solved the issue.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue long time ago. The problem was that IE8 doesn't understand `split` method. The solution was to implement `split` by yourself.

You can use [this example](http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/cross-browser-split)

Comment: +1 Definitely something I'll keep in mind in my future projects.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this `mydate` is not native string, but something more complicated so it treats `split` as its own property. Try converting it to string first:

```
var date = jsonData.list[i].mydate.toString().split(" ")[0];
```